# Creating multilevel dictionary from a list of tuples

Tags: python, defaultdict

I have list of tuples showing relationship between nodes:
`key_value = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'E'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F')]`

From this list of tuples, I would like to create a dictionary tree. So that:

1. First element in each tuple is parent process and second element is the tuple is child process and they should be like {"A": {"B": {} ...
2. If child process does not appear as parent process in other tuple like 'D' then its value should be empty dictionary {}.

So final output should be:

`dict_tree = {'A': {'B': {'C': {'D': {}, 'E': {'F': {}}}}}}`

I tried below but not near to solution

```
from collections import defaultdict
dict_tree = defaultdict(dict)
key_value = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'E'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F')]

for level, value in key_value:
    dict_tree[level][value] = {}

print(dict_tree)
```

OUTPUT:

```
defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {'A': {'B': {}}, 'B': {'C': {}}, 'C': {'E': {}, 'D': {}}, 'E': {'F': {}}})
```

How can I approach this further?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd go with this:

```
key_value = [
    ("A", "B"),
    ("B", "C"),
    ("C", "E"),
    ("C", "D"),
    ("E", "F"),
]

dict_tree = {}
dicts_by_name = {}
for key, value in key_value:
    target = dicts_by_name.setdefault(key, {})
    if not dict_tree:  # no root yet, so install it
        dict_tree[key] = dicts_by_name[key]
    target[value] = dicts_by_name.setdefault(value, {})

print(dict_tree)
```

The output is

```
{'A': {'B': {'C': {'E': {'F': {}}, 'D': {}}}}}
```

which corresponds to your output (even if the print order is different).

Comment: thanks. What is the purpose of dicts_by_name?

Comment: As it says on the tin, to keep track of the dicts so it's easier to put the reference to the `F` dict into the `E` dict, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

i think you are looking for something like this:

```py
key_value = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'E'), ('C', 'D'), ('E', 'F')]

def create_dict_tree(parent, key_value):
    child_dict = {}
    for k, v in key_value:
        if k == parent:
            child_dict[v] = create_dict_tree(v, key_value)
    return child_dict if child_dict else {}

parent = 'A'
dict_tree = {parent: create_dict_tree(parent, key_value)}
print(dict_tree)
```

Comment: Since you initialized child_dict as an empty dict, the inline condition when returning is not necessary (return child_dict is sufficient).